# Adding attr within class with name=name[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

In the example below, I can add an attribute 'id' to a class='container'
But I don't know how to add an attribute 'id' to one of the inputs.
Let's say I wanted to add an attribute 'id' to an input with name='name[]'

how can I do this?

```
<div class='container'>
    <input name='amount[]' />
    <input name='other' />
</div>

function addID()
{   
    $('.container').attr('id', 'containerID');

}
```

Comment: Why would you do this? `input[name=name[]` obviously is going to refer to many HTML elements because why else would you put the name value as an array if no other elements will be sharing the same name value?

Comment: I need to add an ID because other field defends on its current value. I didn't paste all my code here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.container input[name="amount[]"]').attr('id', 'foobar');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: This is also basic CSS stuff too, which you should sort of know before even starting JavaScript, never mind jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function addID()
{   
   $('.container input[name="name[]"]').attr('id', 'inputID');
}
```

Comment: @RPM hey.. feel free to see her question. She said: '**Let's say I wanted to add an attribute 'id' to an input with name='name[]'**' . Oh come on

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work:

```
function addID()
{   
  $('.container input[name="name[]"').attr('id', 'containerID');

}
```

But be aware that if it returns more than one matching input they'll all get the same `id`. `id` should be unique on the page.

Comment: missing closing bracket